# iOS Memory spikes on CollectionView [high resolution] images

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, alamofireimage, kingfisher

I have a CollectionView with cells having UIImageView. Some images in the list have really high resolution of 3000 x 2000 upwards. I'm using AlamofireImage Library to show and cache images but it still has huge spikes. I tried doing

```
let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: imageView.frame.size)
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, filter: filter)
```

This didn't have much of a change.

Is there a better way to resize/downgrade resolution on downloading an image but before displaying it as iOS memory spikes are more because of resolution than actually the image file size.

Comment: Please try and use auto release pool around the code block. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @iChris I tried that but it didn't help. Still getting 1 second memory spikes till 300-400 MB.

Comment: I've deleted `nuke` tag because it's compositing app for VFX.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

This is how I resize my images. You could process them before displaying.

```
// Resize to ~1.5Kx2K resoultion and compress to <200KB (JPEG 0.2)
private func resizePhoto(_ originalPhoto: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    var size: CGSize
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    if originalPhoto.size.width > originalPhoto.size.height { // Landscape
        size = CGSize(width: 2016/scale, height: 1512/scale)
    } else { // Portrait
        size = CGSize(width: 1512/scale, height: 2016/scale)
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    originalPhoto.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let resizedPhoto = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let scaledPhotoData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedPhoto!, 0.2)
    //print(">>> Resized data size: \(scaledPhotoData!.count)")
    return UIImage(data: scaledPhotoData)
}
```

Comment: 1. Wouldn't a UIImage extension been better ? 
2. Any idea how much ms this would take process an image ?
3. Wouldn't this just resize all to 1.5Kx2K ?

Comment: HI @AkashPopat. Adding this to an extension is a good idea, and I could also pass the desired resolution as a param as well.   In this case, I wanted to limit my image size to 1.5K to 2K pixels and the overall file size to less than 200Kbytes (they all were taken with the back side camera).  Besides reducing the resolution, the compression factor (0.2) also helps reducing the file size. Re: the time to process, it is really fast. No more than a few milliseconds, and highly convenient considering the upload time of a full resolution image.